# Calculate BMI MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I just started learning Matlab so, I was trying to solve Calculate BMI Problem 44945. As I am trying to do so, I encountered the following error:

```
Error using assert
The condition input argument must be a scalar logical.

Error in Test1 (line 3)
assert(all(abs(bmi_calculator(hw) - bmi_correct) < 1e-4))
```

```matlab
function bmi = bmi_calculator(hw)
   % Convert the height values from inches to meters
   h = hw(:,1).* 0.0254
   % Convert the weight values from lbs to kilograms
   w = hw(:,2) .* (1/2.2)
   % Calculate the bmi for height and weight combination and return the output variable 'bmi'
   bmi = w/(h.^2);
end
```

Comment: Try: `bmi = w./(h.^2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the `assert` is part of a test your teacher wrote? It actually fails because your result `bmi` is a two dimensional matrix while it is supposed to be a vector. Try some input for multiple persons like `[9,200;9,200]` and check the sizes of your variables.

Comment: hw is a matrix with two columns the first is thebheight and the second is the width, so I can't give a vector input, because I need tow colunms

Comment: I used the wrong variable name, meant bmi. Updated my answer.

Comment: thank, i just figure it out. you right bmi should be a vector. to do that i just need to add (.) next to / so the formula will be : bmi = w./(h.^2)